# Executing local function code on a remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, shell-scripting

I am updating about 20 bash scripts that perform various server-side operational tasks, checking status / sending reports etc. On some environments these scripts will run locally, on others they need to run remotely. The scripts should detect whether they need to run remotely or locally and 'do the right thing'

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate the foo report

execute_host=appdev7

if [[ "$execute_host" != "$(hostname)" ]]; then
    # ssh-agent will provide passwordless logon
    ssh "$execute_host" < $0
else
    # run report
    echo "Report"
fi
```

Some of the scripts use shared functions and environment variables. I can pass through environment variables using the ssh SendEnv option, but I can't figure out a nice way to make shared functions available when running remotely.

./shared.sh

```
# Shared functions and variables

export report_host="appdev7"

function run_report() {
    # run report
    echo 'Report'
}
```

./example

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate the foo report

[[ -f shared ]] && source ./shared.sh

export execute_host="$report_host"

if [[ "$execute_host" != "$(hostname)" ]]; then
    # ssh-agent will provide passwordless logon
    ssh -o SendEnv='report_host' "$execute_host" < $0
else
    # This doesn't work when the script is run remotely
    run_report
fi
```

- I can place `shared.sh` on all our hosts, but I have to keep the files in sync somehow and that will inevitably go wrong at some point.
- I can place `shared.sh` on an NFS share, but if NFS goes down we lose the ability to use our scripts
- I could scp `shared.sh` to the server before running the script. This would work but might be a little slow, and if `shared.sh` depends on some other script we would have to copy that file too
- I can use `declare -f` to extract the code of my functions, but I can't figure out a nice way to shuffle them over to the remote server. Function dependencies might also cause problems.

About the cleanest solution I can find is to run the shared library inline using [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate the foo report

# source the shared code/vars if we're running locally
[[ -f shared.sh ]] && source shared.sh

execute_host="$report_host"

if [[ "$execute_host" != "$(hostname)" ]]; then
    # ssh-agent will provide passwordless logon
    # Note that we source the shared library in-line with the script
    ssh -T "$execute_host" < <(cat shared.sh $0)
else
    run_report
fi
```

My questions then:

1. Are there any problems with this approach?
2. Can you see a way to avoid referencing the shared library in multiple places?
3. Any way to resolve dependencies in `shared.sh`? (eg if `shared.sh` depends on `shared2.sh`)
4. Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107610/shell-script-run-function-from-script-over-ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

We now have a function like this:

```
function remote::run() {
  # usage: remote::run "host" "includes" "commands"
  # where "includes" is a list of functions to export to
  # the remote host

  [[ -n "$2" ]] && includes="$(declare -f $2);"
  ssh -T $1 "$includes $3"
}
```

This allows us to do things like (contrived example):

```
function status::report() {
  date
  host $(hostname)
}

remote::run $REMOTE_HOSTNAME status::report 'echo status report:; status::report' > out
```

It's far from perfect but it's less ugly than what we had :)

**Previous answer:**

It was difficult to follow the flow of control in the scripts above, I think I'm settling on something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate the foo report

# source the shared code/vars if we're running locally
[[ -f shared.sh ]] && source shared.sh

if [[ "$report_host" != "$(hostname)" ]]; then
    # ssh-agent will provide passwordless logon
    runner="ssh -T -o SendEnv=report_host $report_host"
else
    # run report locally
    runner="bash"
fi

report="$($runner << EOF
    $(declare -f run_report)
    run_report
EOF
)"

echo "$report" | mail -s "daily foo report" root
```

I'm not thrilled about the remote code being in a heredoc. As long as it remains as a few declares followed by a simple function call I think it's okay.

Answer (score 2):

So what I have been using to accomplish this task is a different approach.
First I created an executing script called `remotely`<sup>1</sup>:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage:
# Put this thing as a shebang into your scripts
# i.e.:
# 
#   #!/bin/remotely user@your-server.com
#   
#   echo "hello world from ${hostname}"
#

login=$1
script=$2

args=${@#$1}
args=${args#$2}

tar cz $script | ssh $login "tar xz && bash --login $script $args"
```

And then use it in my scripts that should be executed remotely:

```
#!/bin/remotely user@your-server.com

echo "hello world from ${hostname}"
```

It can also be tweaked to support multiple hosts using something like `gnu-parallel`.

- [1]: https://gist.github.com/Overbryd/6760582

Comment: +1 for the cool idea! It doesn't suit our use case because we want to mix local and remote code in the same script, but it's cool nonetheless :)